# Update a column of text file and write to the outputs with variable names

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a record of items with their ID and price, and try to update the price of some of those items according to another "reference file", whose format is Item# NewPrice OutFile. Ultimately, we will have as many output records as the # lines in the ref file (here 4 outputs). The OutFiles will be similar to the original files except for the adjusted item. Below are my files and the awk script that is not working. I appreciate your help.

```
Main file  [Item # current_value]:
Item  1  20 
Item  2  30
Item  3  40

Reference file  [Item# new_value outputfile]
1  22  It1_22
1  25  It1_25
2  32  It2_32
3  45  It3_45

Expected Output files:
(It1_22)
Item,1,22
Item,2,30
Item,3,40

(It1_25)
Item,1,25
Item,2,30
Item,3,40

(It2_32)
Item,1,20
Item,2,32
Item,3,40

(It3_45)
Item,1,20
Item,2,30
Item,3,45
```

My script does not generate any file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","};FNR == NR{a[$1]=$2;d=$3;next} $2 in a{print $1,$2,a[$2];next}1' ref  main > d
```

Comment: Explain your logic for the desired output.  It1_22 replaces Item 1 price from 20 to 22.  Ok.  But It2_34 replaces Item 1's price and Item 2's price as well.  There should be 5 files no?  Or you want the highest price for each item only?  The highest price for item 1 is 26 so ...

Comment: I did expand all my desired output files. Hopefully, this explains my logic. For any output, only the designated item in the reference file will be changed. The script should skim through the reference file and update only the specific item in each line.

Comment: Well explained, and you got a response quick.  I would have not done better myself (probably worst in fact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and unlimited open files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
NR == FNR {
    vals[$3][$1] = $2
    next
}
{
    for ( fname in vals ) {
        print $1, $2, ($2 in vals[fname] ? vals[fname][$2] : $3) > fname
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk ref main
```

```
$ head It*
==> It1_22 <==
Item,1,22
Item,2,30
Item,3,40

==> It1_25 <==
Item,1,25
Item,2,30
Item,3,40

==> It2_32 <==
Item,1,20
Item,2,32
Item,3,40

==> It3_45 <==
Item,1,20
Item,2,30
Item,3,45
```

You can do the same using any awk, it'll just run a bit slower as it has to open/close each output file for every write as opposed to gawk where it'll only do that when necessary to avoid a "too many open files" error:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "," }
NR == FNR {
    vals[$3,$1] = $2
    fnames[$3]
    printf "" > $3
    close($3)
    next
}
{
    for ( fname in fnames ) {
        print $1, $2, ((fname,$2) in vals ? vals[fname,$2] : $3) >> fname
        close(fname)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ed, thanks a lot for the scripts. I wonder if you can please briefly explain the flow of the first version of the script by karakfa?  awk -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR {n[$2]=$1; v[$2]=$3; next} {for(k in n) print n[k],k,k==$1?$2:v[k] > $3}' main ref

Comment: You're welcome. You should ask @karakfa to explain their script.

Comment: Your latter code is fast and useful. I am trying to understand it. Can you please explain the logic and flow?

Comment: Strangely, I am getting error when re-running the code as tst.awk ref main --> C:/Program Files (x86)/MKS Toolkit/mksnt/awk.exe: Syntax error  Context is: >>>     \       <<<      Any thought?

Comment: SInce there's no ```\``` in my script my best guess is you copy/pasted it incorrectly and added a ```\``` somewhere.

Comment: I think the script is pretty straight-forward after a glance at the awk man pages but do you have anything specific you found unclear in it that you'd like me to clarify?

Comment: Specifically I can not understand  vals[$3,$1] = $2.  What does this line do? What are each field referring to?

Comment: `$1` is the first field (space separated value in the current input line), `$2` the second field, `$3` the third field. `vals[]` is an array indexed by the concatenation of `$3` and `$1` and containing `$2` at that index. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

here is one solution without any error handling for missing values, etc.
To maintain the order of the data file, associate each with the line number and recover while printing.

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{k=$2; n[k]=$1; v[k]=$3; ord[NR]=k; next}                        
                       {for(i=1;i<=length(ord);i++) 
                          {k=ord[i]; 
                           print n[k],k,k==$1?$2:v[k] > $3}}' mainfile reffile 
                                        
$ head It*
==> It1_22 <==
Item,1,22
Item,2,30
Item,3,40

==> It1_25 <==
Item,1,25
Item,2,30                                                                                                      
Item,3,40                                                                                                      
                                                                                                               
==> It2_32 <==                                                                                                 
Item,1,20                                                                                                      
Item,2,32                                                                                                      
Item,3,40                                                                                                      
                                                                                                               
==> It3_45 <==                                                                                                 
Item,1,20                                                                                                      
Item,2,30                                                                                                      
Item,3,45
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is an smart code. The only thing is the output lines are in reverse order, .i.e  Item,3,40 , then Item2, and last Item 1. Is it easy to fix?

Comment: since the arrays are actually associative arrays the iteration order may be different from the insertion order, though for small number of entries with integer keys it should be maintained. Regardless, I added another array to maintain the original order.

Comment: I am getting a Syntax error with the new code:  Syntax error  Context is:
>>>     ,NR==FNR{k=$2; n[k]=$1; v[k]=$3; ord[   <<<

Comment: looks fine to me, make sure you copy/pasted correctly. There seems to be a comma before NR, which shouldn't be there in your error message.

Comment: I figured it has something to do specifically with ord[NR]=k statement. Not sure what?

Comment: It shouldn't be a real problem with the script as written but `ord()` is the name of a function in GNU awk's `ordchr` library so generally avoid using it as a variable name.

Comment: `length(ord)` would fail in some awks since it's undefined behavior in POSIX where `length()` can only take a string arg, not an array.

Comment: You could also run into a "too many open files" error due to not closing the output files as you go, just depends how many output files the script creates and which awk variant you're running.

Comment: You can also run into problems with an unparenthesized ternary expression in some contexts in some awks , see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588714/why-awk-nr2-1ors-ors-n-give-syntax-error/588743#588743.

Comment: Could you briefly explain the flow of the first version of the script?   awk -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR {n[$2]=$1; v[$2]=$3; next}
                  {for(k in n) print n[k],k,k==$1?$2:v[k] > $3}' main ref